# Backup SharePoint 2007 and restore to another location

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

In order to run some load test I need to backup a live site and restore it to my staging server. Both are SharePoint 2007.

I have been through the process and with the exception of minor url changes everything seemed to work well.

The problem i have now is that any lists that had associated worflow no longer seem to be attached to each other and are therefore not triggering.  Having looked at the code in SPD i can see that all the listID's are the original system list id's.  On my new system these lists etc all have new ID's.

I would have that that SPD would have known to update these ID's, surely i cannot be expected to update all these manually?

Regards,

S

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at Sharepoint Workflow Migrator : http://spwflmigrator.codeplex.com/ even though it does not look like to be maintened anymore, it could still get you started on automating the process.

Otherwise, you're correct, it looks like to be manual.